# no-math option in polyglossia package

Tags: math-mode, polyglossia, musixtex

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279563/174620) answer works perfectly for the MWE provided there, I've a different MWE which uses package `polyglossia`. As far as I know `fontspec` is loaded by `polyglossia` automatically. (correct me if I'm wrong.) Thus I can't add `[no-math]`. If I try to load `fontspec` separately with this option (keeping polyglossia intact), it results with some errors. This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % Uncommenting results in errors.

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \akkoladen{{1}{2}{3}{5}}
        \startextract
        \notes
        \en
        \notes
        \en
        \zendextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Load `fontspec` before loading `polyglossia`.

Comment: Oh yes. It was quiet simpler than I expected. What change does the order make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `fontspec` before `polyglossia`.

A package can't be called twice with different options; since `polyglossia` does

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
```

without options, you can't later load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option. However, loading it first with the options you want is good.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % Uncommenting results in errors.
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \akkoladen{{1}{2}{3}{5}}
        \startextract
        \notes
        \en
        \notes
        \en
        \zendextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)